# JMeter - out of memory on linux

Tags: ubuntu, memory, jmeter

I am trying to run a load test for a application. For this i am using JMeter (v.2.13) on an Ubuntu Vm with 60GB Ram and more than enough CPU power. Goal is to reach 10k Users connected via WebSocket.

However during the test runs i get the following errors on the ssh-console (at approx. 1.5k to 2.5k simulated users)

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f20ee653000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /jmetertests/jm/bin/hs_err_pid1833.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f2218de8000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

The mentioned error report file looks like this

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2798), pid=1833, tid=140472285792000
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.4
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

I tried to allocate more memory by modifying the jmeter.sh through adding the following line right before the java-command is issued in the .sh-file:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms5g -Xmx20g -Xss300k"
```

I also tried setting the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable with the following command

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms5g -Xmx20g"
```

And finally I found this command im some SO-thread

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=500000
```

The `top`-Command gives me the following information on memory

```
KiB Mem:  61836576 total, 15163400 used, 46673176 free,    10636 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.    94492 cached Mem
```

## UPDATE

FYI: I do not use any listeners in JMeter except the simple data writer. However errors are thrown even if I disable that last listener.

```
java -Xms40g -version
```

is succesful - so i can really allocate so much memory

I reduced the stack size by using

```
-Xss300k
```

which helped ot at least changed something as I now get a

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
unable to create new native thread. See log file for details.
```

error. It seems that the number of threads on the system are exhausted?

## Update2

as requested by some user the results uf `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
pending signals                 (-i) 491456
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
open files                      (-n) 500000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
max user processes              (-u) 491456
... all other entries are set to 'unlimited'
```

and the limits.conf contains the following entries

```
*         hard    nofile      900000
*         soft    nofile      900000
root      hard    nofile      900000
root      soft    nofile      900000
```

Additonally i have set the `threads-max` under `proc/sys/kernel` to something ridiculous high and also increased the value of `proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`

Did I miss something or did i do something wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay meanwhile i figured it out:

1. make sure to read Dmriti T's post
2. set the java's stacksize to something small - usually the smallest value will be enough. In my case 200k (see also point 4.)
3. increase the maximum *number of open files* in the sysctl.conf (see point 4)
4. increase heap size - but as jmeter will create a lot of threads also leave enough space for the memory the threads will need on OS level (so a new thread needs memory on OS and java heap - therefore leave the os enough memory too) (see below)
5. update the `limits.conf` (see below)
6. update the sysctl.conf-file (see below)

## limits.conf

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
*         hard    nofile      900000
*         soft    nofile      900000
root      hard    nofile      900000
root      soft    nofile      900000
```

## sysctl.conf

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
kernel.pid_max=999999
kernel.thread-max=999999
vm.max_map_count=999999
fs.file-max=999999
```

attention: is pid**_**max and thread-max

## jmeter.sh / jmeter.bat

you will find those in the `/bin/` folder of your jmeter installation.

under linux add the line

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xmx15g -Xss250k"
```

somewhere before the actual java call on the last line. This will decrease the stacksize allocated for each thread.

under windows you have to edit the jmeter.bat.
I have no configured it under windows but at least regarding the heap there should be a line starting with `set HEAP`. I dont know where to put the `-Xss` parameter under windows.

Answer (score 4):

First of all check if you can allocate as much as 50G heap by the following command:

```
java -Xms50G -version
```

If it doesn't succeed - try reducing minimum heap size unless you see your Java version information without errors.

As long as you're **NOT** getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error I believe that your heap size tunings are successfully applied.

Perhaps you have a memory-intensive listener enabled, like [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) or [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table)? If so - disable them (as well as any other listeners)

If possible try switching to Oracle JDK as at least for Java 6 there were immense performance differences.

Also make sure that you following recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your advice - it contains some good info. Please see the updated question. In Short: yes i can allocate the memory specified by ``-Xmx`` and no i am NOT using any listeners except the simple data writer (error occurs even without that listener)

Comment: regarding the JDK i am currently checking how to set it up. I will update my post as soon as i figured it out.

Comment: It looks like that you experience problems with your OS limits. Inspect output of `ulimit -a` command and `/etc/security/limits.conf` file contents. Worth looking at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread as well

Comment: i have already modified the values there but added them in the main question above