# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)

Tags: java, java-11

**Facing below error -**  While install and running one of my own application.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000008a660000, 1973026816, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)

KiB Mem :  3852964 total,   358468 free,  3011660 used,   482836 buff/cache

KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   515060 avail Mem
```

*Space allocation are as below* My system is consuming space as below details

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           377M   42M  335M  12% /run
/dev/xvda1       97G   47G   51G  48% /
tmpfs           1.9G  188K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
tmpfs           377M     0  377M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           377M   32K  377M   1% /run/user/119
tmpfs           377M     0  377M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Any help ?

Comment: 358468 KiB is about 350 MiB. You cannot commit 1881 MiB with only 350 MiB of free space. Instead of posting *disk* usage (which is irrelevant because there's no swap) please post info about the processes using *RAM* (refer to https://www.networkworld.com/article/3516319/showing-memory-usage-in-linux-by-process-and-user.html for guidance); if a Java process is using excessive RAM please provide a heap snapshot. You may also need to pay for a larger server/allocation.
**Edit - I see that this question is really old - why did it (specifically) get bountied?**

Answer (score 1):

[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002612/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning) :

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to
> continue.
>
> Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate xxxxx bytes for
> committing reserved memory.
>
> **Possible reasons:**
>
> - The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
> - In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
>
> **Possible solutions:**
>
> - Reduce memory load on the system
> - Increase physical memory or swap space
> - Check if swap backing store is full
> - Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
> - Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
> - Decrease number of Java threads
> - Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
> - Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
>
> If you are on Java 8 or later, please also see this question: [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize)

More information about issue and resolutions at:

[Memory problem: 'error=12, Not enough space'](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204266124-Memory-problem-error-12-Not-enough-space-)

[Forking JVM: error=12, Cannot allocate memory or error=12, Not enough space](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/forking-jvm-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-or-error-12-not-enough-space-302809889.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20received%20error%3D12,allocates%20memory%20when%20executing%20processes.)

[ERROR: "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000aaaa0000, 178978816, 0) failed; error=Cannot allocate memory"](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/516904?language=en_US)

Of course [Java HotSpot VM Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html) would be useful too.